# Joomla Arabic and English Multilingual

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I have developed a website in English using Joomla's latest version. Now I need to use Arabic also (Multilingual website).

I have installed Arabic language package from the backend. Is it compulsory to use any component / extension for Multilingual ?

Please give me proper suggestion for this.

Comment: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/1159/how-to-setup-a-new-multi-language-website/10347#10347

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install additional extensions to make it work, but you will need to know how it works!

You will need to add Arabic as a language (installing the language alone will not do it), you will then need to enable the language plugins, and you will need to create multiple menus (each for a language). Also, if the modules are different for each language, then you will need to create different modules for the Arabic language, you will then need to assign these modules to the Arabic menu.